# I'm trying to sort my created data set in SAS, but now even when I remove the sorting function, my code does not run, can someone help me?

Tags: sas

Here is my code

```
data cities.admit;
length city state population $15;
length zipcode $3;
input city $ state $ zipcode $ population $;
cards;
Jacksonville Florida 32034 949611
Miami Florida 33101 442241
Tampa Florida 33601 384959
Orlanda Florida 32789 307573
Hialeah Florida 33002 223109
Henderson Nevada 89002 317610
Reno Nevada 89433 264165
Enterprise Nevada 89113 221831
Paradise Nevada 89074 191238
Sparks Nevada 89431 108445
Philadelphia Pennsylvania 19019 1584981
Pittsburgh Pennsylvania 15106 302407
Allentown Pennsylvania 18001 123328
Erie Pennsylvania 16501 97369
Reading Pennsylvania 19601 89872
;

proc print;
var city state zipcode population;
title 'CityInformation - Homework 1';
run;

proc sort data=cities.admit out=sortedOutput;
key population / descending;
run;
```

Comment: Please provide the error in the logs. I don't see any syntax error in your code.

Comment: Check the length of zipcode vs. what is in your actual data.

Comment: When I run the code as posted/shown, I only get one error - library cities is not defined. Otherwise it runs as expected. Note that you will not see output generated for the proc sort unless you print the sorted data set which you do not. You can run a proc contents on the sortedOutput data set to see the output.

Comment: Your PROC SORT step does not appear to have BY statement.  What is that KEY statement?

Comment: If library cities is not defined, there's your main problem. You need a previous LIBNAME statement that tells SAS which directory the data is stored in, assuming that it is reading from an external file. E.g. "libname cities 'C:\SAS\data" if that is where you want to save the data. If you just want a temporary copy, you can use work.admit instead and it will save it within your session only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BY statement is used with many SAS procedures and it is critical to include it in a PROC SORT step as that is how you tell PROC SORT which variables to sort by.

I think perhaps you wanted to sort the data so the cities with the largest population values appear first.  The DESCENDING keyword is placed before the variable that it applies to.

```
proc sort data=cities.admit out=sortedOutput;
  by descending population;
run;
```